# Append new tag with style property from parent tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create image zoom icons. the rich-text-editor i'm using writes something like

```
<p>
  <a title="" data-original-title="" href="myimage.jpg" class="lightbox gallery cboxElement" rel="lightbox[145]">
     <img style="padding-left: 10px; float: right;" src="myimage.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive-rte" height="140" width="130">
  </a> 
here' some text ......
</p>
```

to each image.

unfortunately the css-content-property can't be used with img, so i need to prepend/append a tag in order to position the icon.

I'm using 
`$("<div class='enlargeicon'></div>").appendTo('.cboxElement');`
to add the tag.

So far so good: I need to add also the get the value of the float for each image and insert it to the div for the icon.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
$("<div />", {class: 'enlargeicon'}).appendTo('.cboxElement').css('float', $('.cboxElement').children("img").css('float'));
```

Edited. Try it again, pls.

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eam299fq/). It seems to work.

Make sure that the element that is the parent has the property that you want to be inherited.

Edited: to get the `float` position of the `img` element. :) Thank you for your suggestion [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1418261/jason).

Comment: thank you for your instant answer.
... but there's no effect.

Comment: $("<div class='enlargeicon'></div>").appendTo('.cboxElement').css('float', $('.cboxElement').css('float'));

wirtes the float-property - but allways 'none', even if the img has right or left.

Comment: Rather than writing the HTML as a string (which does function) consider applying the attributes as an object for a cleaner implementation. `$("<div />", {class: 'enlargeicon'}).appendTo...`

Comment: thank you for your help!!

i edited your fiddle to show up multiple images and changed the class to .img-responsive-rte. but it doesn't seems to work with multiple img.

Answer (score 0):

use this syntax.

```
var imageFloat = $('.cboxElement a img').css('float'); // get the float value of the img
$("<div class='enlargeicon' style='float:"+ imageFloat  +"'></div>").appendTo('.cboxElement');
```

Answer (score 0):

i realized that i have to loop through the document. the alert shows up the correct value of each float. but how can i insert this value inside of the span?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.img-responsive-rte').each(function(i) {
    //alert($(this).css('float'));  
    $(this).after('<span style="float:  ">');
})


});
```

thanks a lot

i also tried this, which outputs the correct value for each float -  but also inside the img-tag (instead of after). how do i have to change it to make it work?

```
$('.img-responsive-rte').each(function() {
  var x = $( this ).css( "float" );
  $( ".img-responsive-rte" ).html( "That div is <span style='float:"    x + ";'>" + x + "</span>." );       
});
```

thank you for your reply

is it possible at all to get the within a tag by using after, append, html or anything else?